# What do to when OP changes question with an edit?

Tags: discussion

This question:

[I got my bank account closed abruptly how do I get money out?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/67415/i-got-my-bank-account-is-being-closed-how-can-i-persuade-them-to-keep-it)

was kind of marginal to begin with.  It got several answers (including one from me).  Then the OP changed the question by editing it. (Originally it was "How do I get my money out?" and now it is "How do I convince the bank to keep it open?")

I answered the original question, but I just voted to close the question as edited since the former question, while arguably obvious, had clear answers but the latter question is just going to lead to speculation and opinion.

What is the right thing to do here though?  No "standard" option seems right since usually the question does not fundamentally change over the course of a couple of days.

Answer (score 12):

This comes up pretty frequently on other network sites, see e.g.

[Rolling back a completely changed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64459/rolling-back-a-completely-changed-question)

The right thing to do is to roll back the question so the original answers remain valid, and advise the OP to post a new question if appropriate (probably not in this case as you say).

I've rolled it back now.